# IE9 displaying selected items even when selected=""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a series of drop downs that let the user select multiple items from the same overall list of available options.

Each drop down contains the same basic list, but if an item is selected, that option will not appear in the other lists. The page loads with one or more of these selected.

The drop downs can be removed. When this happens, the selected option is added to the other lists so that it is available.

I've code jQuery code to remove a drop down, remove the "selected = 'selected'" value from that option, take the value that was previously selected, and add it to the other lists. It all works fine except for IE9- it hangs onto the "selected" bit and resets all the drop downs to have the previously removed item as the selected option.

```
$(".removestccode").click(function () {
    var $ddl = $(this).parents(".stcCodeLi").find("#ddlSTCCode");
    $ddl = $(this).prev();
    var $liPrev = $ddl.find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    alert($liPrev[0].outerHTML);

    var ddls = $('.ddlSTCCode').not($ddl);
    for (var i = 0; i < ddls.length; i++) {
        var d = ddls[i];
        $(d).append($liPrev[0].outerHTML);
        //$(d).find("option").tsort();
    }

    if ($("#ulSTCCodes li").length > 1) {
        $(this).parents(".stcCodeLi").remove();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wicker95/g2mdqg4v/

The alert is there to demonstrate the value being appended to the other lists.

I know there are a couple of id's are being used more than once on the  tag, because... reasons.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no valid reason to use an ID more than once.  It's illegal HTML, and the browser is allowed to do anything it wants to when you feed it garbage.  I don't care what your reasons are, don't do it.  Fix this issue, because illegal html is the #1 cause of problems in web pages, because the browser will just do whatever it wants when it finds it.  Even if you figure out a way to make this work, there is no guarantee that the next rev of any given browser won't go off and do something even more weird because of illegal markup.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch- While you're correct that this is "illegal markup", this comment is not helpful. "because...reasons" is shorthand for "the markup is generated by something I don't control, and for the sake of brevity, on what is already a long question, I'm not going into the various reasons". Right now, I want to make the almost three versions old version of IE work. I'll worry about future browsers later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker suggested this modification, which worked:

```
$(d).append($liPrev[0].outerHTML.replace('selected=""', ''));
```

In context:

```
$(".removestccode").click(function () {
    var $ddl = $(this).parents(".stcCodeLi").find(".ddlSTCCode");
    $ddl = $(this).prev();
    var $liPrev = $ddl.find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

    var ddls = $('.ddlSTCCode').not($ddl);
    for (var i = 0; i < ddls.length; i++) {
        var d = ddls[i];
        $(d).append($liPrev[0].outerHTML.replace('selected=""', ''));
        //$(d).append($liPrev[0].outerHTML);
        //$(d).find("option").tsort();
    }

    if ($("#ulSTCCodes li").length > 1) {
        $(this).parents(".stcCodeLi").remove();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on line 4 of your jsfiddle JS code:

```
var $liPrev = $ddl.find("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

`.prop()` is what what you need to set instead of `.removeAttr()`

You can also do `.attr('selected', null)` to remove the attribute

Comment: @silkster- This doesn't make any difference. The property is still present, which translates to the item being selected. While the property itself is a boolean field, IE9 seems to be treating its mere presence as true.

Comment: You also could do .attr('selected', null) to remove the attribute;